# Google Omaha installer hangs

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I'm trying to get Google Omaha to work, and even though I feel I'm really close for some reason it is not.

I've read the few guides and tutorials available online for it and finally managed to get the client built. I've also installed the docker package provided by Crystalnix and as far as I can tell everything is setup as it should.

For some reason however the installation process gets stuck after the API request for the package information is made.

The last response from the server looks as follows:

```
<response protocol="3.0" server="prod">
  <daystart elapsed_seconds="62157" elapsed_days="4372"/>
  <app status="ok" appid="{XXX-XXX-XXX}">
    <updatecheck status="ok">
      <urls>
        <url codebase="http://updates.example.com/static/media/build/Product/stable/win/78065329307666/"/>
      </urls>
      <manifest version="71.0.57.18">
        <packages>
          <package required="true" hash="6uZwsU9+WCZ1oR3ovGnFyrTCqhM=" name="install.exe" size="59309528"/>
        </packages>
        <actions>
          <action successsaction="default" run="install.exe" event="install"/>
        </actions>
      </manifest>
    </updatecheck>
  </app>
</response>
```

After this request is being retried for three times the installer hangs with this error: Unable to connect to the Internet.  If you use a firewall, please whitelist ProductUpdate.exe

What could the issue for this be?

LE: this is the complete Omaha log file https://pastebin.com/QALnk7X7

Comment: Will the URL to executable file be valid: `http://updates.example.com/static/media/build/Product/stable/win/78065329307666/install.exe`? Also, I would enable logging to find out more info. Here's how to do it: https://github.com/google/omaha/blob/master/doc/ClientLog.md

Comment: @Asesh the path being formed is valid and trying to access the URL using a browser triggers the file download. Also, regarding logging, I did that but unfortunately no errors are being thrown but only the fact that the requests are being attempted.

Comment: BTW is that ``install.exe`` app Chromium's mini installer or Omaha client updater? If it's either one, then Omaha client expects certain return values. Also remember Omaha client will log download/install/update complete events and their corresponding time too.

Comment: The install.exe is indeed a Chromium mini installer. The issue is however that Omaha never gets to the point of downloading the mini installer to begin with. I know that because I tried the process with and without Fiddler installed, and could see the requests being made in Fiddler. It's seems to be as if the response from the server wasn't a successful one.

Comment: You should checkout the Omaha log file. It should display whether that XML data was successfully sent to the server or not. It will display response too which again is an XML file too. It will also contain data on if a file was successfully downloaded or not etc.

Comment: I've added a link to the complete log file above

Comment: hmm does that mini installer install w/o passing any arguments? Looks like you have not passed any arguments to it from your Omaha server. Will it work if you pass ``--system-level`` argument from your server? Let me know. If it won't then I will have to test it from my development machine

Comment: Downloading and double clicking the installer.exe installs just right. Also, adding the "--system-level" argument does not seem to change anything. Still the same error.

Comment: Looks like it's happening because of Omaha server. I see this error code: ``0x80040880`` which is equivalent to ``OMAHA_NET_E_CUP_NO_SERVER_PROOF ``. More info: https://github.com/google/omaha/search?q=OMAHA_NET_E_CUP_NO_SERVER_PROOF&unscoped_q=OMAHA_NET_E_CUP_NO_SERVER_PROOF

Comment: Downloading of packages is handled here: https://github.com/google/omaha/blob/3061c8410a86115c4ff581799f2990b451a62c05/omaha/goopdate/download_manager.cc in this method: ``HRESULT DownloadManager::DownloadApp(App* app)`` You should debug your code, also Omaha client uses multi-process architecture so it will be a little tricky to debug it